# How can I call a method of a specific object that is stored in an arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

I have an arraylist that holds instances of a class I created. I want to call a method from the class I created on the object at a specific index of the arraylist. I know I can do this with a regular array assuming class 'Object' has a method '`printName()`', and that the array is filled in between creation and the call to `array[i].printName()`:

```
Object[] array = new Object[20];

/////////////////////////////////
// Fill the array
/////////////////////////////////

array[i].printName();
```

I can't figure out how to do this same thing, but with an array list. Here is a snippet what my problem is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

// Check for correct # of arguments
if(args.length != 1)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Port>");

// Initialize Server
serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
portList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
usernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
serverData = new byte[MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
serverPacket = new DatagramPacket(serverData, serverData.length);
serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);
System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | Listening for client requests... |");

// Loop forever, starting a new thread for each incoming client request
while(true) {
    try{

        // Block until a packet is received from a client
        serverSocket.receive(serverPacket);
        // Set clientPort to the port from which the packet was received
        clientPort = serverPacket.getPort();

        // If this packet is from a known client forward the message to proper recipient(s)
        if((clientIndex = clientList.indexOf(clientPort)) >= 0) { 
            clientThread = clientList.get(clientIndex);
            if(clientThread.sendPacket(serverPacket) < 0)
                System.err.println("[" + getTime() + "] | Message was not delivered |");
            continue;
        }
```

I want to call the `sendPacket()` method of the ServerThread stored at index clientIndex in clientList.

EDIT: I'd like to do this without using a for loop to iterate through the whole arraylist looking for a match, but if that is the only possible way I will do that

EDIT2: Updated code with more info

Comment: Why are you using `indexOf(clientPort)`? Do you not already know the index? If you have an object to pass to `indexOf`, you should be able to just call `clientPort.sendPacket(whatever)`.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the difference between arrays and arraylists. The direct translation of the array-based code is `arraylist.get(i).printName();`. If you had the index in the ArrayList case, it'd be as easy as the array example.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a Map from ports to threads?

Comment: Sorry fixed a typo and added more code, but I want to find the index of a port stored in the arraylist portList, and then use that index to find the corresponding ServerThread at the same index in the arraylist clientList

Comment: Then you want a map from ports to ServerThreads.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have clientPort, why are you looking for the index? Just call `clientPort.sendPacket(serverPacket)`. If it depends on `clientPort` contained in the List, put it into an `if` statement like this:

```
if (clientList.contains(clientPort)) {
    clientPort.sendPacket(serverPacket);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Map is suggested in this situation. Use port as Key and ClientThread instance as value. Any special concern for using List?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I've edited the answer. But when I want to comment on author's post, it says I need 50 reputation.